# Open links on other section of FrameSet

Tags: html, xhtml, html4

I am using following code to split my screen into two panes.

```
<frameset cols="20%,80%">
 <frame name="lefty" src="menusidebar.html">
 </frameset>
</frameset>
```

The file "menusidebar.html" contains links. I want to open the links on the right pane when the user clicks on the link in the left-pane. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you're missing the other (right) frame, let's call it righty. To direct links from one frame to another you should use the target attribute of the anchor tag. See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#h-16.3). But basically something like:

```
<a href="..." target="righty">click</a>
```